# functions with multiple values not returning

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

    fun multiplyAndDivide(number: Int, factor: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
        return Pair(number * factor, number / factor)
    }
    val (product, quotient) = multiplyAndDivide(4, 2)

    fun multiplyInferred(number: Int, multiplier: Int) = number * multiplier
}
```

Please I have spent hours trying to execute these codes but nothing is happens.
I only get

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What do you expect to be happening?

Comment: 1.fun multipyAndDivide should return both the product and quotient of the two parameters by returning
a Pair containing two Int values.2. for fun multiplyInferred the return type is inferred to be
Int since both number and multiplier are Ints.

Comment: Your code appears to do just that, and it executes successfully (as indicated by the exit code of `0`). Are you expecting to _see_ something?

Comment: So what do you expect to be happening when you run the code? Your previous comment doesn't say

Comment: @Doe You need to print the result: `println("$product, $quotient")`

Comment: ok thanks I thought with return you do not need print statement.

Comment: marstran It worked. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way you can use Pair in Kotlin to return multiple values from function:

```
fun returnTwoValues(): Pair<String, Int>{

    return Pair("string_result", 15)
}
```

How to Access result:

```
val p = returnTwoValues()

val result1 = p.first

var result2 = p.second
```

To see the Result print it like this:

```
println("$result1, $result2")
```